# unknown language inserted in mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to develop  a PHP script to insert Arabic language in mysql db, but the issue when I insert the data thru PHP code I got a unknown language, as show below.

Snapshot of unknown language:

[image]

as I'm using the below PHP script to insert the data .

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert test</title>
<form action="insert_data_script.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="text" value="name">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</head>
</html>
```

as the **insert_data_script.php** will include the below ;

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "abrazaqc_cyclist";
$password = "xxxxxx";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql ="INSERT INTO  `abrazaqc_test`.`insert` (
`idinsert` ,
`info`
 )
VALUES (
NULL ,  '" . $_POST["text"] ."'
)";



if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

**Notes: snapshot from table:**

[image: table]

- I have tried everything, but I can't solve the issue .
- I hope someone can help me to solve the issue .

Comment: This will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify you are using UTF-8 when you connect to mySql with PHP:

Add the following code when you connect to the DB:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

Comment: I have test that, but I got same issue .

Comment: Did you try msqli_query instead of msql_query?

Comment: msqli_query isn't php code ! whatever I have tried it, but it doesn't work